# How to print value of register in nasm assembly

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, printf, nasm

I'm trying to have the user enter a number, then print 1,2,3...[value]

I have the following that is called after entering a number

```
printnum:
    mov ecx,0                   ;start at 0
    mov bl, [value] 
    jmp printnumloop    


printnumloop:
    cmp     ecx, 0
    jle     actuallyprint
    jmp     menu

actuallyprint:
     mov    rdi, [format]
     mov    edi, ecx
     mov    eax, 0
     call   printf

    mov     rdi, [LC8]
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    add  edx, 1
```

LC8 is

```
LC8:    db  " , ",0
```

according to the debugger, the error is on this line

```
=> 0x00007ffff7aa8ae3 <+35>:    movdqu xmm0,XMMWORD PTR [rdi]
```

Comment: `mov    edi, ecx`  <-- what's this? did you mean to write `mov esi, ecx` ?

Comment: I was trying to move the counter variable into the register to be printer, which should be rsi or esi.  It's something with the formatting though, because the error it's giving is in strcrnul, not in my code.

Comment: You haven't shown us the format string.

Comment: format:  db "%d",0x0D,0x0a,0

Comment: that would have it print each number on a new line. Changed it to just "%d"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the address of the strings, not their value. Don't dereference `format` and `LC8`.  Right now, you're passing in the first 8 characters of the string, not a pointer to the string.  Its hard to know for sure without more context, but it looks like the instruction you're getting the segfault on is probably `printf` dereferencing the format string parameter.  In your example, the first 8 characters of the string don't happen to be a valid memory address, so an error occurs.

```
actuallyprint:
     mov    rdi, format ; pass pointer to format
     movzx  rsi, ecx ; pass register contents by value
     mov    eax, 0 ; probably don't need this
     call   printf

    mov     rdi, LC8
    mov     eax, 0
    call    printf
    add     edx, 1
```